# Laravel Testes Unitário. Não consigo instanciar a classe

Tags: php, laravel-5

meu problema aparentemente é simples, mas eu não consigo resolver.

Resolvi fazer testes na minha aplicação, e já no começo tive problemas

Eu executo a seguinte linha de comando para rodar o teste:

```
vendor/bin/phpunit
```

No teste eu só estou instanciando a classe User:

```
$user = \Escola\User;
```

E recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> ```
> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  
> Undefined constant 'Escola\User'                                                                                         
> Fatal error: Undefined constant 'Escola\User' in  
> /home/f15/Desktop/escola/tests/PedidoTest.php on line 11
> ```

Comment: ja tentou colocar um `new` antes de `\Escola\User` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa usar a *keyword* `new` pra instanciar algo

```
$user = new \Escola\User;
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo. Agora foi :)

Comment: Por nada. Não sei se você sabe, mas pode sempre marcar a resposta que mais te ajudou como correta. Só marcar o **V** do lado esquerdo da resposta

Comment: Marcado. Eu tinha assinalado na hora, mas precisava esperar uns 5 min. Então eu marquei agora a noite mesmo. Obrigado mais um vez!!!! :)